# Is there a way to use vertical and horizontal pod autoscaler without a controller?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to know if there is a way to use autoscalers in Kubernetes with pods directly created from a "pod creation yaml files" not the pods created as part of a higher-level controller like deployments or replicasets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no.

`Horizontal Pod Autoscaler` changes the number of replicas of a `Deployment` reacting to changes in load utilization. So you need a `Deployment` for it to work.

Regarding `Vertical Pod Autoscaler`, I think it should work with spare pods as well, but only at Pod creation time. In fact, I read the following statement in the [Known limitations](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler#known-limitations) section of the README:

> VPA does not evict pods which are not run under a controller. For such
> pods Auto mode is currently equivalent to Initial.

That sentence make me conclude that VPA should work on Pods not backed by a Controller, but in a limited way. In fact, the [documentation about `Initial` mode](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler#quick-start) states:

> VPA only assigns resource requests on pod creation and never changes
> them later.

Making it basically useless.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to use `Pod` object as the target resource for an HPA.

The [document describes HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) as:

> The Horizontal Pod Autoscaler automatically scales the number of Pods
> in a replication controller, deployment, replica set or stateful set
> based on observed CPU utilization (or, with custom metrics support, on
> some other application-provided metrics). Note that Horizontal Pod
> Autoscaling does not apply to objects that can't be scaled, for
> example, DaemonSets.

The document also described how the algorithm is implemented at the backend as:

```
desiredReplicas = ceil[currentReplicas * ( currentMetricValue / desiredMetricValue )]
```

and since the Pod resource does not have the replicas field as part of its spec therefore we can say that the same is not supported for auto scaling using the HPA.

---

Although it seems the VPA does support working with `Pod` object but there is a limitation when using VPA just with `Pods`.

> VPA does not evict pods which are not run under a controller. For such
> pods Auto mode is currently equivalent to Initial.

You can read about the different `updatePolicy.updateMode`s in the [docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler#quick-start).